# Calculate $sum with default value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to calculate total spending per specific call.

I am collecting orders with specific callId and then sum totalPrice attributes from the result.

It works, except if there is no order, I get an empty array. I would like to get 0 as default value for totalSpending instead.

This is my query:

```
Order.aggregate({
    $match: { callId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(callId) }
}, {
    $group: { _id: null, totalSpending: { $sum: '$totalPrice' } }
})
```

If there is no order I get an empty array, if there is at least 1 order  I get `[ { _id: null, totalSpending: 50 } ]` for example.

Comment: The aggregation pipeline is evaluated sequentially. You can just look for empty array and return the `totalSpending`  as 0

Comment: is this possible inside aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

Use `$project` with `$cond` instead of `$match`. This overwrites the non-matching `callId` document `totalPrice` to 0.

```
 Order.aggregate({
    $project: {
        totalPrice: {
            $cond: [{
                $eq: ["$callId", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(callId)]
            }, "$totalPrice", 0]
        }
    }
 }, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        totalSpending: {
            $sum: '$totalPrice'
        }
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need an $ifNull clause in sum, if it it null is will return totalprice in sum otherwise it will return 0;

```
Order.aggregate({
    $match: { callId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(callId) }
}, {
    $group: { _id: null, totalSpending: { 
        $sum: { 
                $ifNull: ['$totalSpending', 0] 
            }
    }
})
```

Comment: Still get an empty array. The problem is that $group pipeline isn't called at all if $match doesn't return any result.

Comment: You can do it use collection.count to check if it exists and count of orders is not 0. If it is, then you can return array of totalSpending as 0 . If count is more than 0 then you can go for above aggregation.

Comment: Yeah, but this required additional query. I would like to make it in 1 query.